# Drop primary key without dropping an index

Tags: postgresql, index, primary-key, ddl

Is it possible to drop primary key constraint on a table without dropping the index? I have a situation when I want to remove the `PRIMARY KEY` to get rid of the `NOT NULL` constraints and set it to another column pair. I want to avoid dropping and recreating the index. Can just the `PRIMARY KEY` 'attribute' on the index be dropped? Dropping the constraint removes the index.

I am using PostgreSQL version 9.1.

Comment: I think there is no way to do this. The constraint "owns" the index. When it is removed, the index goes as well.

Comment: You can promote an index to primary key with `alter table NameOfTable add constraint NameOfPrimaryKeyConstraint primary key using NameOfExistingIndex`, but I don't think the reverse is possible.

Comment: If you are worried about the time it takes to create the index after dropping it and the potential vulnerability to your data during that window - you could always create the new index BEFORE you drop the constraint..

Comment: You might be able to do it by hacking `pg_depend` to break the dependency between the index and constraint, but that might just cause errors in the `DROP CONSTRAINT`. I don't think there's a supported user-level way to do this.

Comment: I ran a quick test converting a simple `PK` to a `UNIQUE` constraint after identifying the OID for the `pg_constraint` entry. I also set `pg_class.relhaspkey` to `false`. Like `UPDATE pg_constraint
SET    contype = 'u'
WHERE  oid = 23456;
UPDATE pg_class
SET    relhaspkey = false
WHERE  oid = 'contents'::regclass;`  But that still didn't do it. Still could not create a new PK: `ERROR:  multiple primary keys for table "contents" are not allowed`. So there is more .. I stopped there. I'd rather not try and mess with the system catalog for a relevant table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there is a supported way to do this. Consider the comments so far.

If you are concerned about effects on concurrent transactions, there is a [code example in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-altertable.html):

> To recreate a primary key constraint, without blocking updates while
>   the index is rebuilt:
>
> ```
> CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CONCURRENTLY dist_id_temp_idx ON distributors (dist_id);
> ALTER TABLE distributors DROP CONSTRAINT distributors_pkey,
>     ADD CONSTRAINT distributors_pkey PRIMARY KEY USING INDEX dist_id_temp_idx;
> ```

For your case, you could create the same index the PK uses a second time *and*  the index used by your new PK. Then drop the PK like in the example, add a *different* (unlike the example) PK based on the new index and a new `UNIQUE` constraint based on the duplicated former PK index. All in a single statement. That would only lock the table for a millisecond.
Three separate commands (not in one transaction):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CONCURRENTLY dupe_of_old_pk_idx ON tbl (old_pk_id);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CONCURRENTLY new_pk_idx ON tbl (new_pk_id1, new_pk_id2);

ALTER TABLE tbl
   DROP CONSTRAINT tbl_pkey
 , ADD  CONSTRAINT tbl_uni  UNIQUE USING INDEX dupe_of_old_pk_idx
 , ADD  CONSTRAINT tbl_pkey PRIMARY KEY USING INDEX new_pk_temp_idx;
```

Comment: Thank you. I was aware of this solution and you are right. I just wanted to avoid the I/O on production server while creating the duplicate index, which is not possible (or unsupported/undocumented) right now as stated in your answer and comments.

Comment: Looking at your answer more closely, is there any reason the commands can't be run in one transaction?

Comment: @xchg You cannot run `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY` in a transaction - it would defeat the idea behind using `CONCURRENTLY`, namely avoid blocking.

Comment: @xchg: What dezso said. Plus, it wouldn't buy you anything to run the `CREATE INDEX` statements inside a transaction - except keeping more locks for an extended period of time - not what you would want.