# Avoid unique violation in atomic transaction

Tags: postgresql, transaction, unique-constraint

Is possible to create atomic transaction in PostgreSQL?

Consider I have table category with these rows:

```
id|name
--|---------
1 |'tablets'
2 |'phones'
```

And column name has unique constraint.

If I try:

```
BEGIN;
update "category" set name = 'phones' where id = 1;
update "category" set name = 'tablets' where id = 2;
COMMIT;
```

I'm getting:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "category_name_key"
DETAIL:  Key (name)=(tablets) already exists.
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In addition to what [@Craig provided](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/104992/3684) (and correcting some of it):

Effective Postgres **9.4**, `UNIQUE`, `PRIMARY KEY` and `EXCLUDE` constraints are checked immediately **after each row** when defined `NOT DEFERRABLE`. This is different from other kinds of `NOT DEFERRABLE` constraints (currently only `REFERENCES` (foreign key)) which are checked **after each statement**. We worked all of this out under this related question on SO:

- [**Constraint defined DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE is still DEFERRED?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10032272/939860)

It is **not** enough for a `UNIQUE` (or `PRIMARY KEY` or `EXCLUDE`) constraint to be `DEFERRABLE` to make your presented code with **multiple statements** work.

And you can **not** use <strike>`ALTER TABLE ... ALTER CONSTRAINT`</strike> for this purpose. [Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-altertable.html)

> `ALTER CONSTRAINT`
>
> This form alters the attributes of a constraint that was previously
>   created. Currently **only foreign key constraints may be altered**.

Bold emphasis mine. Use instead:

```
ALTER TABLE t
   DROP CONSTRAINT category_name_key
 , ADD  CONSTRAINT category_name_key UNIQUE(name) DEFERRABLE;
```

Drop and add the constraint back in a **single statement** so there is no time window for anybody to sneak in offending rows. For big tables it would be tempting to conserve the underlying unique index somehow, because it is costly to delete and recreate it. Alas, that does not seem to be possible with standard tools (if you have a solution for that, please let us know!):

- [Drop primary key without dropping an index](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/103074/drop-primary-key-without-dropping-an-index/103112#103112)

For a **single statement** making the constraint deferrable is enough:

```
UPDATE category c
SET    name = c_old.name
FROM   category c_old
WHERE  c.id     IN (1,2)
AND    c_old.id IN (1,2)
AND    c.id <> c_old.id;
```

A query with CTEs also is a *single* statement:

```
WITH x AS (
    UPDATE category SET name = 'phones' WHERE id = 1
    )
UPDATE category SET name = 'tablets' WHERE id = 2;
```

**However**, for your code with **multiple statements** you (additionally) need to actually defer the constraint - or define it as `INITIALLY DEFERRED` Either is typically more expensive than the above. But it may not be easily feasible to pack everything into one statement.

```
BEGIN;
SET CONSTRAINTS category_name_key DEFERRED;
UPDATE category SET name = 'phones'  WHERE id = 1;
UPDATE category SET name = 'tablets' WHERE id = 2;
COMMIT;
```

---

Be aware of a **limitation** in connection with `FOREIGN KEY` constraints, though. [Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtable.html)

> The referenced columns must be the columns of a **non-deferrable unique
>   or primary key constraint** in the referenced table.

So you cannot have both at the same time.

Answer (score 13):

As I understand it, your issue here is that the constraint is checked after each statement, but you want it checked at the end of the transaction, so it compares the before-state to the after-state, ignoring the intermediate states.

If so, that is possible with a *deferrable constraint*.

See [`SET CONSTRAINTS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set-constraints.html) and `DEFERRABLE` constraints as documented in [`CREATE TABLE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html).

Note that deferred constraints have costs - the system has to keep a list of them to check at commit time, so they're not good for transactions that make huge sets of changes. They are also slower to check.

So I think you probably want to:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER CONSTRAINT category_name_key DEFERRABLE;
```

Note that there appears to be a limitation on `ALTER TABLE` setting constraints to `DEFERRABLE`; you might have to instead `DROP` and re-`ADD` the constraint.