# Add composite primary key on existing PostgreSQL table

Tags: postgresql, index, primary-key, alter-table

I have a table on PostgresSQL with millions of rows. The table has columns a and b. I already have a unique index on a and b:

`CONSTRAINT a_b UNIQUE (a, b)`

I want to add a composite primary key on columns a and b.

Will there be any downtime if I do a

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD PRIMARY KEY (a, b);
```

Comment: There is no real difference between your existing unique constraint and a primary key. So why do you think you need the primary key?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I need it due to pg_logical replication

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! You could set up a little test to check times with a few thousand records and see what happens then? Don't forget to drop your constraint after you create the primary key!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will there be any downtime?

While [`CREATE INDEX`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html) only blocks concurrent writes and still allows reads, you need [`ALTER TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) to add the `PRIMARY KEY` constraint, and that takes an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock on the table, blocking reads, too. So, **yes**, if the table is essential, I would call that "downtime".

**However**, there are options to alleviate the pain.

First, both index columns must be **`NOT NULL`**. While a `UNIQUE` constraint / index allows `null` values, the PK does not. If that's not the case, fix it first. Else, the later `ALTER TABLE` will do it for you, extending the downtime. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html#id-1.9.3.35.5)

> If [...] the index's columns are not already marked `NOT NULL`, then
> this command will attempt to do `ALTER COLUMN SET NOT NULL` against
> each such column. That requires a full table scan to verify the
> column(s) contain no nulls. In all other cases, this is a fast
> operation.

So, first (after fixing any `null` values):

```
ALTER TABLE public.demo
  ALTER COLUMN a SET NOT NULL
, ALTER COLUMN b SET NOT NULL;
```

Then, the question is: unique **index** or **constraint**? An index can be repurposed in a very fast "metadata only" operation. The same is not possible for a constraint, unfortunately. One might think it should be: it's still the same index. But it's just not implemented. Too rare a use-case that anyone would have bothered. You can probably hack the system catalogs. But I am not going there. One false move and you can break the entire database. There was a similar request in the past, and I didn't go there, either:

- [Drop primary key without dropping an index](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/103074/drop-primary-key-without-dropping-an-index)

So, if it's a constraint, build a second, otherwise identical, unique **index** first. Use a temporary name, it will later be thrown out the window. We have the non-blocking [`CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html#SQL-CREATEINDEX-CONCURRENTLY) for the task since Postgres 8.2 (almost forever now).

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CONCURRENTLY a_b_temp ON demo (a,b);
```

Finally, drop the constraint, and add the PK building on the existing or new *index*:

```
ALTER TABLE public.demo
  DROP CONSTRAINT a_b  -- if it was a constraint
, ADD  CONSTRAINT demo_pkey PRIMARY KEY USING INDEX a_b_temp;  -- "a_b" if it was an index
```

This takes said `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock. But all the hard work has already been done, so it should be a matter of milliseconds - as soon as concurrent transactions let it take the lock.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/A5UbwJHG)